# Relative Sorting Algorithm Based On 2 Related Variables

Tags: algorithm, vba, sorting, ranking

I have a bunch of video games I like, but I like some more than others. I have assigned them all a ranking 1 - 100 inclusive (not necessarily all integers are used and some may be used twice, although this can be changed if needed).

I have a list in excel with three columns: name of video game, rating (1-100), date last played, and a VBA macro button that says "kick" to bottom (more on this below).
When I assign a video game a ranking of 1, I want to be reminded to play it ideally every week.
When I assign a video game a ranking of 100, I want to be reminded to play it ideally every 52 weeks.

I defined reminded as "floating" to the top of this list in excel. So all games are slowly floating to the top (highly rated ones just faster than others) to remind me to play them. If I "kick" one to the bottom because I was reminded to play it, the counter/date on that video game starts over.

I'd imagine for this to work games will have to "pile up" at top, because many of them may have their due dates at a closely related times.
I think a perfect solution exists but it doesn't have to even be perfect.

How can I go about solving this problem?

Comment: you need a "last played" date column, and a "next play" date column. "Next play" column is populated with a formula based off the last play date and the ranking.  Sort ascending on "next play"

Comment: So this would work. But I guess one thing you'd want to account for randomness. So maybe there is a blizzard and I play 10 times as much for a week. I would be "ahead" of the queue and none would be visible to me.

Comment: So just play whatever is at the top of the queue?